# HTML Report for Squish for web

Tags: html, report, squish

I have an Squish for Web for automating web application. I would like to know whether HTML report will be generated for Squish and steps to generate it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To generate an HTML report you need to execute the test suite without the Squish IDE, as described in [How to Do Automated Batch Testing](https://doc.qt.io/squish/automated-batch-testing.html) (but also see [Automated Batch Testing](https://doc.qt.io/squish/how-to-do-automated-batch-testing.html)):

**Step 1 - Launch squishserver in background:**

Unix:

```
squishserver --verbose &
```

Windows:

```
start /b squishserver --verbose
```

**Step 2 - Execute test suite:**

```
squishrunner --testsuite suite_mine --reportgen html,report_folder_name
```

**Note 1:** After the execution the report can be viewed by opening the "index.html" file in the folder denoted by "report_folder_name".

**Note 2:** If the folder denoted by "report_folder_name" does not exist, it will be created.

**Note 3:** If the folder denoted by "report_folder_name" exists, it must be a Squish HTML report folder, and the results of this new test suite execution will be added to the existing report.

Answer (score 0):

2 steps to get HTML reports in squish

1. start Squish server, I used CMD with squish folder

   ```
    squishserver --host 127.0.0.1 --port 4233
   ```
2. Then use below command and yes add ur test suit too in Squish Bin folder

   ```
   squishrunner --testsuite <suitname> --reportgen html,<folderName>
   ```